# Accessing action name within action in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to use the connector action name in the action itself? For example, on a HTTP request action, sending in the body the action name?

[image: Diagram view]

[image: Code view]

In this example, the action name actually goes as a x-ms-workflow-operation-name header. However, I cannot use any self @action()/@actionBody('---')/etc  expression (throws an error).

Answer (score 0):

No.  The description of the Action is purely a Design-Time convenience.  There's no expression evaluation at all.

The closest you can get is using the same Parameter in your deployment template to set the same value in both places.